# How do I set access control so I can get Batch entry? It's not showing up

Tags: civicontribute

Batch Entry is not showing up for us.  I've been told it might be something with access control however, I need help figuring out who I look at access control to turn this feature on.  I do have a version of Civi that has the feature (CiviCRM 4.2.7.) so I know it's available.  Can anyone help me figure this out so I can use the feature for recording donations?  Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the CiviCRM permissions within your host content management system? They override anything in your CiviCRM ACLs.

Comment: Please post your CMS software (Drupal, Joomla, or Wordpress) and the version of your CMS?

Comment: We have Drupal.

Comment: Graham, I'll take a look at this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So Civicrm has two main ways to grant or restrict access:

- permission: it's more "high level" and it's about granting access to big features, eg to administer events or view anything about financial contributions
- Access Control (ACL): it's mostly so a group of user see only a subset of your contacts, for instance the media people only see the journalists

In your case, it's most probably a permission issue, not access control one. Where you set these permissions depends on your CMS, because it's related to the users and their roles.

There is a rather long list of permissions you can grant, including a few about batch (eg. "CiviCRM: create manual batch, Create an accounting batch", check what applies to your case for this user.

If you don't see a change in the menu when you grant extra access, you might need to logout/login so the new rights are taken into account

Comment: adding this as a comment rather than an alternate answer. There are CiviCRM permissions for eg "CiviCRM: create manual batch
Create an accounting batch (with Access to CiviContribute and View Own/All Manual Batches)" - your user role will need to have these ticked. They were added during some upgrade hence it is possible that your permissions were not updated at the time

Comment: Xavier - I checked our permissions (in Drupal)  I didn't see any mention about any permissions for batch. I was told by the Civi team that the version of Civi has batch as a standard feature  - would it be possible somehow it was stripped out of our setup?